# Storing the data into dictionary with count

Tags: python

I have 2 text files that look like the ones below:

**input.txt**

```
shoes
memory card
memory card
```

**input1.txt**

```
shoes
shoes
```

i want to store the data in a dictionary query will be my key. and count will be my value.input.txt and input1.txt is my two input.in the format **word : [count of word in input.txt,count of word in input1.txt]**
like below:-

```
op:- 
shoes:[1,2]
memory card:[2,0]
```

Comment: Count of what? words shoes in a file, or every word? Please be clear.

Comment: @Marchin yes count of word in input.txt and input1.txt

Comment: And what is a query? Can you provide specific example, input and expected output.

Comment: @Marcin query is word only.

Comment: @Marcin that i have given in my question.

Comment: OK, so if I understand correctly then you want every unique word in the input files to be a key in a dictionary which has a value in the form of a list stating how many times that word appeared in each text file?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach with normal loops:

```
    i = 'shoes\nmemory card\nmemory card'
    i2 = 'shoes\nshoes'
    dict = {}
    i = i.split('\n')
    i2 = i2.split('\n')
    for ele in i:
        if ele not in dict:
            dict[ele] = [1,0]
        else:
            dict[ele][0] +=1

    for ele in i2:
        if ele not in dict:
            dict[ele] = [0,1]
        else:
            dict[ele][1] +=1

    print dict
```

Comment: actually i am getting all the data from json file. so i dont know where i am getting error.

Answer (score 0):

You could do as follows:

```
from collections import Counter


with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines1 = [l.strip() for l in f]

with open('input1.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines2 = [l.strip() for l in f]

# count the number of occurrences of your words in each file
c1 = Counter(lines1)
c2 = Counter(lines2)


out_dict = {}

# for each unqiue word from both files, 
#put its count int the out_dict.
for k in set(c1) | set(c2) :
    out_dict[k] = [c1.get(k,0), c2.get(k,0)]

print(out_dict)
```

The result is:

```
{'shoes': [1, 2], 'memory card': [2, 0]}
```

Comment: i have post my code can you find out why i am getting wrong output

Answer (score 0):

actually i am getting data from some json file.

```
 import os
 import json
 auto_prefix = u'\u200B'
 path1 = "/home/mine/new-log/1-search-logs-01-20/"
 dict = {}
 for path,dirs,files in os.walk(path1):
 for data in files:
    with open("/home/mine/new-log/1-search-logs-01-20/"+data) as text:
        for line in text:
            file2 = json.loads(line)
            try:
                query = (file2["appData"]["_request_params"]["params"]["q"])[0]
                if auto_prefix in query:
                    query = query.replace(auto_prefix,"")
                    query = query.encode('utf-8').lower()
                    if query not in dict:
                            dict[query] = [1,0]
                        else:
                            dict[query][0] += 1
                else:
                    query = query.encode('utf-8').lower()
                    if query not in dict:
                            dict[query] = [0,1]
                        else:
                            dict[query][1] += 1
            except KeyError:
                pass
 print dict
```